# Coping with simple database with username and password

Tags: python-3.x

I am a learner as well as a new user of Python 3.5.1
I am trying to work out a simple feedback program on just creating accounts stored in lists as well as logging in them. I am supposed to give feedback to users if they have successfully logged in or had a wrong password. I am intended to use the module function, but I would like to keep it simple and avoid using it if possible. Here are the codes which I have done and it just won't work.

```
user={}
import lib`

while 1:
    print("Welcome to the login portal.")
    print("Do you have an existing account? y/n")
    answer=input()
    if answer==("y").lower():
        login()
    if answer==("n").lower():
        create()
    if answer==("q").lower():
        quit()
    else:
        tryagain()
```

**Where as in the lib file, the codes are:*

```
def tryagain():
    while 2:
        print("Please try again or press q to quit.") 
        print("Do you have an existing account? y/n")

def create():
    print("Please create a username and password.")
    print("Username: ")
    createun=input()
    print("Password: ")
    createps=input()
    print("Account creation successful. Please login to continue.")
    login()

def login():
    print("Please enter your username: ")
    loginun=input()
    if createun==loginun:
        print("Please enter your password: ")
        loginps=input()
        if createps==loginps:
            print("Account validation successful.")
        elif createps!=loginps:
            print("Password incorrect. Please try again.")
    else:
        print("Login Failed!")
if __name__== "__main__":
    print("Module successfully loaded.")
    input("Press the enter key to exit.")
```

Anyone able to help me?

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to utilize a module for this, it only adds complexity with none of the benefits in this case. Simply define your functions at the top of the file (below all your imports, none in this case) as per general convention. You then call your functions in the `main()` function. Here is one example to do this. This should get you started with what you are looking for.

```
def account_create(userNamePassDict):
    print('Please create a username and password.')
    userName = input('Username: ')
    userPassword = input('Password: ')
    userNamePassDict[userName] = userPassword
    print('Account creation successful')
    return userNamePassDict


def account_login(userNamePassDict):
    print('Please log in using your user name and password')

    userName = input('Username: ')
    while userName not in userNamePassDict:
        print('User name is not recognized. Please try again.')
        userName = input('Username: ')

    userPassword = input('Password: ')
    while userNamePassDict[userName] != userPassword:
        print('Password is incorrect. Please try again.')
        userPassword = input('Password: ')

    print('Account validation successful.')


def main():
    userNamePassDict = {}
    print('Welcome to the login portal.')
    while len(userNamePassDict) != 5: # Keep looping till 5 users have been created
        answer = input('Do you have an existing account? y/n: ')
        if answer==('y').lower():
            account_login(userNamePassDict)
        if answer==('n').lower():
            userNamePassDict = account_create(userNamePassDict)
        if answer==('q').lower():
            break

    print('Here is the User Database:')
    print(userNamePassDict)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Couple of other comments:

- I am not sure what you mean by `while 1` and `while 2`. If you want to create infinite loops, `while True` is a way to do it though there is usually better way.
- `input()` takes a string as an argument that it prompts the user with. You can save yourself a separate print statement.
- When coding something beyond few lines of code, don't write all the code and then test it. It is much easier to write and test it as you go along. Test it early and often as you make changes.